# change label from another viewcontroller on swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to change label from another `viewController`.

First viewcontroller is `MenuController`. Second one is `LoginViewController`.

I want to change MenuController's `Label.text` from `LoginViewController`.

In `LoginViewController`:

```
let viewController = MenuController()
viewController.changeLabel("logout")
```

In `MenuController`:

```
class MenuController: UITableViewController {
    var attractionImages = [String]()
    var attractionNames = [String]()
    var webAddresses = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var loginLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loginLabel.text = "Login"
        print(loginLabel.text)

    }

    func changeLabel(Log: String)O {
        self.loginLabel.text = log
        print (log)
    }
```

But an error occur.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

How can I solve it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dont upload images for code. You can simple copy and paste your code here.

Comment: Post you code here ...

Comment: Sorry guys. Im very new here. Im going to learn how to use Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way to achieve that is you can use `NSNotificationCenter`. Blow is the example for that:

In your `MenuController` add this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshLbl:", name: "refresh", object: nil)
}
```

Also add this helper method:

```
func refreshLbl(notification: NSNotification) {

    print("Received Notification")
    lbl.text = "LogOut"
}
```

Now in your `LoginViewController` your back button action will look like:

```
@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refresh", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now when ever you press back button from `LoginViewController` your `refreshLbl` method will call from `MenuController`.

For more info refer [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/post-notification) example.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3** version:

In your `MenuController` (where the label needs to be changed) add this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
                                           selector: #selector(refreshLbl),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"),
                                           object: nil)
}
```

Also add this helper method:

```
@objc func refreshLbl() {
    print("Received Notification")
    lbl.text = "LogOut"
}
```

Now in your `LoginViewController` your back button action will look like:

```
@IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)
    // Any additional code...
}
```

Now when ever you press back button from `LoginViewController` your `refreshLbl()` method will call from `MenuController`.